# Find matrix for linear transformation L(M) = transpose(M) in the given basis B of 3x3 magic-squares

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, transpose, magic-square

[image: Image of the problem]

I already found a basis B for 3x3 magic-squares, but I am unsure of where to start on part b. Finding the transformation matrix for $L(M) = \text{transpose}(M)$ in said basis.

Comment: @Glen the "homework" tag was eliminated years ago.

Comment: What you need to do, Guy, is, for each of your three basis matrices, write the transpose of that matrix as a linear combination of the three matrices. The coefficients in those linear combinations will be the columns of the matrix you've been asked to construct.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thanks for bringing me up to date. Would the following comment have been more appropriate?
This question appears likely to be a screen shot of a WeBWorK assignment, and as such is presumably homework. Please read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question and edit your posting appropriately. For example, you will note the guidelines specify that you should be sure to "ask a question" as opposed to "give an assignment," and the posting as it stands appears to do the latter. Thanks! – Glen Whitney 9 hours ago

Comment: @Glen, that looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's compute the third column of your matrix: let $M_1,M_2,M_3$ denote the matrices of your basis. We find that
$$
L(M_3) = \pmatrix{0 & -1 & 1\\1&0&-1\\-1&1&0}.
$$
We would like to find (the unique) $x_1,x_2,x_3$ such that 
$$
L(M_3) = x_1 M_1 + x_2M_2 + x_3 M_3.
$$
In this case, we find that $x_1 = 0, x_2 = 0, x_3 = -1$.  Thus, the third column of the  is $(0,0,-1)$. That is, the matrix of $L$ relative to your basis has the form
$$
\pmatrix{?&?&0\\?&?&0\\?&?&-1}.
$$